# Neither RibbonWinForms or Krypton Ribbon have any design time functionality when converted to .Net 6, is this a known feature of .Net 5/6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, krypton-toolkit

I have converted both RibbonWinForms and the Krypton-toolkit to .net 5/6 but neither show any design time functionality. (ie you can't click on the controls and add tabs/panels etc).  Both compile with no issues.  Can anyone point me in a direction of how to fix this or is it just not going to work in .Net 5 or 6?

Comment: Were you able to move past this?

Comment: No, i took a different approach.